# Is there any way to open a IE window using firefox or chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, internet-explorer, firefox

I have an ActiveXControl in my page which reads a registry value of client machine.
It works fine in IE browser.

Where as it does not support in Firefox/Chrome/Safari browsers.

Is there any way to open a IE popup window while my web application is used in Firefox/Chrome/Safari.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Krishna Aditya P

Comment: What if the user doesn't have IE installed?

Comment: IE is usually associated with certain file types. if you download/open one of those file types, IE can/will run to open it. mshtml comes to mind, maybe others.

Comment: There is a browser extension built by google that will do this. Fully manageable by group policies, perfect for intranets that have a mix of old legacy applications that require oldIE and newer applications.

Comment: Just be like one of those websites that **force** the user to use a certain browser. Not only will I attempt to bypass this with fake user-agents, I probably won't even visit your website. :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response guys.Our product support only IE browser until now but they want to support others from now on so I am pretty  much done in converting the files to new compatible code but got struck regarding the ActiveXcontrol.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in normal JavaScript. If you really need to open IE from these other browsers, you'd have to write something like a Java applet or something else that would allow a browser plugin to open an external application. And there's no guarantee that the user has Java installed.

Probably not worth it; better to ask your users to use IE.

Comment: I am not having good knowledge on Java.I am .Net guy so is there a way in .Net?

Comment: Maybe Silverlight can launch processes, though I doubt it. Another thing that I'm personally not familiar with is  in-browser XAML applications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx

Comment: OK, after reading this article, I see that you can actually have a Silverlight application that can run with elevated privileges in-browser, which would let you start IE from other browsers: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/04/27/silverlight-5-beta-rough-notes-trusted-apps-in-the-browser.aspx. Of course, the users would probably have to install Silverlight, then click a confirmation to allow the application to run, and all of that just to launch IE. A warning message that they must open the site in IE would be easier on you and your users.